# I have a ContextMenu inside a TextEdit, I need access data from outside it. Like combobox, lineedit

Tags: c++, qt

I try to send data from inside the textedit context menu and receive other data from outside. From within the menu I can call a slot and send data out of it. But outside of it I can't send data to it. The data arrives empty. How can I do what I need?

```
class ContextMenu : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(ContextMenu)
public:

    template<class TextEdit>
    ContextMenu(TextEdit *edit, const QContextMenuEvent *event)
        : QObject(edit)
    {

        m_text = edit->textCursor().selectedText();
        m_origem_is="tr";

        m_menu = edit->createStandardContextMenu(event->globalPos());
        m_menu->move(event->globalPos());
        m_menu->addSeparator();
        QAction *saveOnTextFile = m_menu->addAction(QIcon::fromTheme("document-save"),tr("Save data to File..."), this, &ContextMenu::callFuncToSaveFile);
        QAction *saveOnAudioFile = m_menu->addAction(QIcon::fromTheme("audio-x-generic"),tr("Save TTS Audio to File..."), this, &ContextMenu::callFuncToSaveTTSFile);
        m_menu->addSeparator();
         if (m_origem_is.isEmpty()){
            saveOnTextFile->setEnabled(false);
            saveOnAudioFile->setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    ~ContextMenu() override;

    void popup();

    QString text() const;

private slots:
    void callFuncToSaveFile();
    void callFuncToSaveTTSFile();

private:
    QMenu *m_menu;
    QString m_text;
    QString m_origem_is;

};
```